# AMPscript as a dedicated activity in Journey Builder?

Tags: ampscript, journeybuilder

We are planning a complex journey within Journey Builder and for some paths of it, we want to execute an AMPscript before particular activities (SMS send). In some cases, we have Email send activities and execute script in them but are there other solutions? For instance, could we perform the script within in some sort of dummy email?

Specifically, we want to update existing Data Extension during the specific stage of our journey.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is Update a specific Data Extension at some point of the Journey then you can easily achieve this by using the "Update Contact" Activity within Journey Builder.

Simply drag the activity in wherever you like and add the settings for the fields.